# Add same (dev)Dependency, but different use in dev & production

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, package.json

I Have two projects:

1. `common_components` repo.
2. `main_project` that use these components.

these two project maintaned and developed parallel.
I use the `common_components` as a devDependency in the `main_project`.

Tho, the `common_components` has two version types, a dev version, that after each push to the dev branch an artifactory is created, and another version that once a week I create a main version artifactory.
for example the dev version is `d.1.0.0` and the main version `m.1.0.0`.

in `main_project` package.json:

```
   ....
  devDependencies:{
  "common_components": '@same-path-for-dev-and-main-version'
  }
```

My problem is that when i run build on `main_project` I want make a difference between the dev and main version of the `common_components`.
when i build:dev i want the `d.1.0.0` version of `common_components` and when i run build:prod i want the `m.1.0.0` version.

is there a way to store the same devDependency with different versions(depends on the build) that it will not collide when i run builds?

I've tried to look for package.json rules but i havent find a solution.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you be more specific? how are you using the version information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install specific versions / tags of all npm dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439053/how-do-i-install-specific-versions-tags-of-all-npm-dependencies)